# Weatherstrip still leaves a gap

Tags: seal

I've tried so many different kerf style weatherstrip, magnetic and foam clad.
Even a fridge style magnetic. The fridge style comes off each time u open the door.

All the others leave a gap on the door lock side.

5 year old house.  Use to be ok  could it be that the frame warped. How can I fix this?

Comment: Photos or a much more detailed description, please.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to apply weatherstripping to?

Comment: Fridge style need a metal piece to connect to to seal a photo of what you are trying to seal would provide some answers that might help you.